# Vuejs transition animation not working on leave

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I'm going down the CSS route of addition transitions using Vuejs. I'm building a basic mobile navigation right now. This is my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/67dcnd7a/1/

My HTML:

```html
    <nav>
        <div id="nav-btn" v-on="click: isVisible = !isVisible">
            NAVIGATION
            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
        </div>
        <ul v-show="isVisible" v-transition="slide">
            <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Explore">Explore</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Adventure">Adventure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Main Region">Main Region</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="The Exchange">The Exchange</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <pre>
            {{ $data | json }}
        </pre>
    </nav>
```

My transition CSS (the rest can be seen in the fiddle for default styling):

```css
    .slide-transition {
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        height: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .slide-enter, .slide-leave {
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

Then my Javascript with my Vue instance:

```js
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    // Navigation instance
    new Vue({

        el: 'nav',

        data: {
            isVisible: false
        },

        methods: {
        }

    });
```

It slides down just fine, but sliding up, it jolts really fast. It doesn't do it smoothly. When I take the opacity off, it looks even worse. The leave CSS rules don't seem to be applying, but they apply on enter.

I rather not use the opacity since that makes it seem more like fading. What I want is for it to SLIDE down and then SLIDE back up, not have any fade effects. I was following their documentation here:

http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html

But I couldn't quite get the effect that they had in their first example.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to animate to and from `height: auto` due to browser implementation issues. It works better if you use an actual metric for height like "5em" instead. I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidkhess/67dcnd7a/2/